# Insert variable containing string as parameter of new list c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have several lists that contain data. I my intention is to display certain indexes of these lists with key presses. The functionality is the same across all lists..."press key, get data". I don't want to write separate functions for each list. Instead, I want to just set a variable equal to "list1", "list2", etc. And then insert that variable string into

```
List<Sprite> newList = new List<Sprite>(controlVariable);
```

So essentially what i'm looking for is this pattern:

```
//...user input to set value of controlVariable (this functionality is not part of this question, i'm only interested in the variable stuff below)
string controlVariable = "list1";
List<Sprite> newList = new List<Sprite>(controlVariable);
```

This would allow me to apply all my code to which ever list i'm trying to work with without having to write new code for each type of list. But the trouble i'm running into is that `controlVariable` is a string and it's trying to be inserted into a parameter that's expecting a different type. I don't know how to get around this. I'm sure someone is going to tell me to use Reflection but i've looked at different examples on the web and I can't figure out how to apply it to my case. I'm new to C#. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) isn't the appropriate collection to use in your case. Have you tried using [Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Dictionaries allow you to retrieve objects based on a given key. In your case, "keys" are strings ("list1", "list2", etc...) and their associated objects (a.k.a. "values") are lists of `Sprite` objects.

```
// Creating a dictionary and adding a key to it
Dictionary<string, List<Sprite>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Sprite>>();
dict["list1"] = new List<Sprite>();
dict["list2"] = new List<Sprite>();

// Retrieving a list of sprites associated to "list1" from the dictionary
List<Sprite> mySprList = dict["list1"];
```

Comment: It looks like OP's dictionary would be `<string, List<Sprite>>` according to that last line of example code in the question.  Other than that, this is a great answer.

Comment: Corrected the code example as suggested by user @clarkitect

Comment: so let me explain a little more. my lists all contain images and i'm creating a randomize feature that cycles over the list and randomly selects an index then displays it. After that I remove the index from a copy of the master list because i don't want to change the master list. I used lists because it has the RemoveAt function. Here is my full code for better clarity. `List<Sprite> newList = new List<Sprite>(controlVariable);
   foreach(Image image in Images){
   int j = Random.Range(0, newList.Count);
   image.sprite = newList[j];
   newList.RemoveAt(j);`

Comment: I have 5 lists and i want to select which list of images to assign to "controlVariable" so that the new "clone" list contains the images of the respective master list selected by the user.

Comment: I believe the example I gave fits your needs. First, you create each of your 5 ("clone") lists in the dictionary, e.g.: `dict["list2"] = new List<Sprite>();` (create each list from "list1" to "list5" in the dictionary). Then, before your `foreach` loop from your last comment, you will be setting `controlVariable` to the name of the list you want to use (e.g. `"list3"`). Finally you can do `List<Sprite> newList = dict[controlVariable];` and use the very same `foreach` code you just posted.

Comment: @maximus1127 Update your question with your little explanation please. That will be usefull.